# Rails Routes Constraints with www is working, domain without www not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

Through another **Rails-Engine** project, I was able to work with constraints better. I tried to take my previous work and modify it to this one.

I have an app that runs off subdomains, `www/admin` is restricted but everything else a customer can use. I used the much simpler:

```
constraint => "www"
```

Since the above method wouldn't work on a URL without `www` and just `example.com`, I was working with the below script:

I put the file in `app/constraints/frontend_router.rb`

```
    class FrontRouter
        def self.matches?(request)
            request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != "www" && request.subdomain != ENV['DEPLOYED_DOMAIN']
        end
    end
```

At the top of the routes file, add the required file. The `www` seems to work but the `example.com` (without `www`), was not.

```
require 'frontend_router'

constraints(FrontRouter) do
    # Landing Page
    scope module: "website" do
        root 'page#index'
    end
end
```

Comment: I actually found out just now this may not be working, I had reset the server and raked routes not showing any constraints.... I'll continue working on this and try to figure it out.

Comment: Re-routing `www`/`non-www` should be done in the DNS - you're adding bloat to a Rails app to try and manage it.

Comment: I have no first hand knowledge, but the DNS uses CNAME and from what I've been reading not really possible at the DNS level to route .example.com to www.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin I'm using is routing everything. It could've overwritten what I was trying to do. But I found this to be my best personal option: is working with the welcome and the separated dashboard views on the engine.

```
 gem 'mtwarden', '~> 2.2'
```

If anybody else has a better solution, I'm willing to try it out and test. But this will accomplish what I need done.